# ImportError: No module named nose.tools

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I encounter some difficulties loading dataset onto my programme. I am unsure of the import error as stated below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Khoo Family\Downloads\lsa_clustering (3).py", line 4, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .base import load_diabetes
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\base.py", line 25, in <module>
    from ..utils import check_random_state
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array, check_arrays, safe_asarray,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .fixes import safe_copy
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .testing import ignore_warnings
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\testing.py", line 36, in <module>
    from nose.tools import assert_equal
ImportError: No module named nose.tools
```

Answer (score 23):

Check if nose in a list of installed python packages. 
You can do it in *python console* (windows + R, type cmd then enter, type python then enter):

```
>>> help('modules')
```

If nose is there, then you either have a problem with PYTHONPATH when running your code or you using another interpreter to run console and your code.

If nose not in a list, do in your *console* (windows + R, type cmd, then enter):

```
pip install nose
```

Comment: I am running it from pycharm - what do you suggest? I see nose as a module

Comment: I probably need more details to understand how to reproduce the problem. PyCharm has nose test runner, but I never used it, since I write usual unittest + mock tests, and use no nose features. To run those from PyCharm I use regular unittest runner. To run the tests with coverage or in parallel I use nose as command line tool.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a file name- "nose.py" in your program folder because of that it is talking that nose.py as a module and not the installed original nose module.

If not installed then please install it with this command.

```
pip install nose
```

Answer (score 2):

You have probably named your file starting with "test_", change it and it should solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, a similar error is caused by `pylint`. So if the error shows `import error(pylint error)`, disable `pylint` in settings.